# MS Access Form alpha numeric fields

Tags: forms, ms-access, alphanumeric

I have a field on an MS Access form that has the following validation rule:

Is Null Or Between 10000000 And 99999999

This basically restricts to the user to be able to enter 8 digits only.

Is there a way to change the validation rule so that the user can enter 8 alpha numeric characters?

Comment: If the form field is bound to a table field, do you also want to enforce that rule for the table?

Comment: @HansUp yes i'd like to enforce the rule for the table as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the ValidationRule property on the field to

```
Is Null Or Like "????????"
```

Comment: i tried this but it still give me an error. If i type in 8 digits...it works fine...but if i put in 8 letters, it shoots out an error: the value you entered isnt valid for this field

Comment: @JT2013 - what's the data type of the field? Should be Text if you want to allow letters; my guess is that it's still typed to an integer of some sort.

Comment: your right, i forgot the most basic thing of all -> change the data type of the field!

Answer (score 1):

One way to enforce this within the user interface would be via an [input mask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa160023%28v=office.10%29.aspx) instead of validation:

```
AAAAAAAA
```

**Update**: As @Chris Rolliston points out, you are better off using validation at the database level to ensure you maintain valid data.  How you do that will vary depending on the db engine (MS Access, SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.) where the table physically resides.

Comment: I'm not sure that's really 'easier', and it certainly won't 'enforce' the requirement in the way a validation rule set in the table definition would.

Comment: @ChrisRolliston: Good point.  It's only easier in the sense that it works the same regardless of back-end db engine.  But I agree that it is safer to enforce this check at the database engine level.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can put VBA in the AfterUpdate event of the object like:

```
If len(Trim(Me.MyTextField)) <> 8 then
  Msgbox "Please enter an 8-digit key"
  Me.MyTextField = ""
End If
```

Make sure the Trim function is in there to eliminate the user trying to add empty spaces.